finding minimum of a dataframe
I have a dataframe that stores the distances between three objects:
df = pd.DataFrame({'obj1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
                   'obj2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'dist': [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0]})

Is there a way I can compute the object that has the min distance for each obj1 other than itself? For the example above return [('a', 'b', 1), ('b', 'a', 1), ('c', 'a', 2)].

Why have both a,b and b,a in the output? Isn't that redundant? But if you want that redundancy, shouldn't you include a,c too?

Please write a more descriptive title. I thought you were talking about DataFrame.min() at first. Check out [ask] if you want tips.

OK, I misunderstood the question in my first comment. I thought the answer you wanted was a and you also wanted the distances in the result. But now I see, for each obj1, you want to find the obj2 with the least distance (excluding obj1==obj2).

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'obj1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], 
                   'obj2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'dist': [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 0]})
#   obj1 obj2  dist
# 0    a    a     0
# 1    a    b     1
# 2    a    c     2
# 3    b    a     1
# 4    b    b     0
# 5    b    c     3
# 6    c    a     2
# 7    c    b     3
# 8    c    c     0

df.loc[df.obj1!=df.obj2].sort_values(by="dist").drop_duplicates(subset="obj1", keep="first")
#   obj1 obj2  dist
# 1    a    b     1
# 3    b    a     1
# 6    c    a     2


You could remove the rows in which obj1 is equal to obj2 (e.g. with query), then use a groupby.idxmin:
out = df.loc[df.query('obj1 != obj2').groupby('obj1')['dist'].idxmin()]

Variant:
df.loc[df.loc[lambda x: x['obj1'] != x['obj2']].groupby('obj1')['dist'].idxmin()]

Output:
  obj1 obj2  dist
1    a    b     1
3    b    a     1
6    c    a     2

As tuples:
out = (df.loc[df.query('obj1 != obj2').groupby('obj1')['dist'].idxmin()]
         .agg(tuple, axis=1).tolist()
      )

# or
out = list(map(tuple, df.loc[df.query('obj1 != obj2')
                               .groupby('obj1')['dist'].idxmin()]
                        .to_numpy()))

Output:
[('a', 'b', 1), ('b', 'a', 1), ('c', 'a', 2)]

